# How to pass arguments to a single command from multiple files?

Tags: shell-script, command, arguments

I am using the convert command to annotate images with text:

```
convert -pointsize 20 -fill green -draw 'text 270,460 "[TEXT TO ANNOTATE]" ' [INPUT IMAGE NAME].jpg [OUTPUT IMAGE NAME].jpg
```

I have 100 images and a single .txt file of 100 unique words with each word on their own line. How can I make it so that every single one of the 100 images gets annotated with the text from a single line of the .txt file? To clarify, I want them to be unique - there shouldn't be more than one image annotated with the same text. I'm new to shell scripting and don't even know where to start.

Comment: The design is no robust, add a stray file and the words won't end up on the right images. It would be quite easy to have a file where lines contain both a file name and the word to apply to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the request correctly, that could be (POSIX `sh` syntax):

```
for file in ./*.[jJ][pP][gG]; do
  IFS= read -r text <&3 || break
  convert -pointsize 20 \
          -fill green \
          -draw "text 270,460 \"$text\"" \
          "$file" "${file%.*}-annotated.${file##*.}"
done 3< /path/to/list.txt
```

(assuming there's no double quotes in the lines of `list.txt`).

That processes all the `.jpg` (case insensitively) files in the current directory in alphabetical order, and for each, one line of text is read from `list.txt`, the jpg is annotate with  the text in that line and saved as `original-annotated.jpg`.